# How should I perform this delegate properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a table view controller and a view controller.

- StackTableViewController - list of strings
- HomeViewController - empty view controller with a label

The HomeViewController label should present always the first sting of the StackTableViewController.

I need to make sure if the first string is deleted to present the new first string.

And this is where I have the problem...if I delete the first string and going back to the HomeViewController, the label is still the string I just deleted....And if I terminate the app and open it again, the correct string shown in the label.

This is How I did it so far:

this is the relevant methods in my StackTableViewController.h + .m:

```
@protocol StackTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

-(void)didDeleteObject;

@end

@interface StackTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> 

@property (strong,nonatomic) id<StackTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *currentTarget;

@end



#import "StackTableViewController.h"
#import "Target.h"
#import "StackTableViewCell.h"
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "CoreDataStack.h"

@interface StackTableViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultController;

@end

@implementation StackTableViewController

- (id)init {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"StackTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Do something
        [self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
        Target *current = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.currentTarget = current.body;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
    Target *current = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.currentTarget = current.body;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    [[stack managedObjectContext] deleteObject:target];
    [stack saveContext];

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDeleteObject)]) {
        [_delegate didDeleteObject];
    }

}
```

And this is the relevant methods in the HomeViewController.h + .m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StackTableViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {

    StackTableViewController *stackTableViewController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *homeLabel;

- (IBAction)goToStack:(id)sender;



#import "StackTableViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController () <StackTableViewControllerDelegate>


@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Do something
        stackTableViewController = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init];
        stackTableViewController.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.homeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:40];

    self.homeLabel.text = stackTableViewController.currentTarget;
}

- (void)didDeleteObject {
    self.homeLabel.text = stackTableViewController.currentTarget;
}

- (IBAction)goToStack:(id)sender {
    StackTableViewController *vc = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

CoreDataStack.h +.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface CoreDataStack : NSObject

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

+ (instancetype)defaultStack;
- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;


@end


#import "CoreDataStack.h"

@implementation CoreDataStack

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

+ (instancetype)defaultStack {

    static CoreDataStack *defaultStack;
    static dispatch_once_t onceTocken;
    dispatch_once (&onceTocken, ^{
        defaultStack = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return defaultStack;
}


- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "digitalCrown.Treats" in the application's documents directory.
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Treats" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Create the coordinator and store

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Treats.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        // Report any error we got.
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}


@end
```

Please help me to solve this, I was tying allot of ways but probably i'm missing something that got to do with view controller lifecycle or something.

(the CoreDataStack is a singleton)

tnx!!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use one Action for both an check the sender and the segue to know where is it coming from:

```
  - (void)unwindFromModal:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue {
        if unwindSegue.identifier == @"createModal" {
             NSLog(@"Got home from create page");
        }

        if unwindSegue.identifier == @"stackModal" {
           NSLog(@"Got home from stack page");
        }
    }


    - (IBAction)presentModal:(UIButton*)sender {
       if sender.tag == 0 {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"createModal" sender:self];
       } 
       if sender.tag == 1 {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"stackModal" sender:self];
        }

    }
```

You can use String Constants in the tags to make more readable and a switch if you prefer too

Comment: No problem with `else if`

Answer (score 1):

There could be two issues need to be fixed here.

1. Delegate method `didDeleteObject` is not called at all. In `goToStack` method you create a new `StackTableViewController` but forget to set its delegate, while you also have a global variable `stackTableViewController` instance. I think you meant to push the global one onto the stack.
2. In `commitEditingStyle` tableview delegate method, you forget to update the `currentTarget` property which is used to update the label text, you can try to update that property and see what would happen.

For 1, you can change the `goToStack` function like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:stackTableViewController animated:YES];
```

Which means `StackTableViewController *vc = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init];` should be removed.

For 2, in `commitEditingStyle` method, after `[stack saveContext]`.

```
[stack saveContext];

//Please add the following code.
NSIndexPath *theIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
Target *current = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:theIndexPath];
self.currentTarget = current.body;
```

Comment: #2 didn't work, can you give more details on #1? thanks

Comment: sorry, but both of the solutions does not work. When I go to stack, delete the first object, and hit "back", the homeLabel is still the string of the object I just deleted...And when I will terminate the app and opened it again the data in the label will be correct

Comment: so weird that no one give me an answer that works...I thought that should be simple...

Comment: In the beginning of `commitEditingStyle`, add this line `NSLog(@"before deletion %lu", self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count);`
, after `saveContext`, add this line,`NSLog(@"after deletion %lu", self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count);`, and print out the value of `current.body` to see if it is updated.

Comment: i.e, before 4, after 3

Comment: What is the value of `current.body`? it should be different than what you see before you enter the page.

Comment: I found that in those two lines: if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDeleteObject)]) {
        [_delegate didDeleteObject];
    } the second line is not being called...iv put a breakpoint there and nothing stopped

Comment: Nil check the _delegate to see if it is nil, the delegate should be the homeViewController.

Comment: it is nil...how come?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at this line `stackTableViewController.delegate = self;` to see if it is executed, it is possible that your init method is not called.

Comment: just checked it and it does gets called :/

Comment: ok now the delegate is the homeviewcontroller, but still I have the same bug if I delete the first object of the table view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67630/discussion-between-gabbler-and-johnbigs).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't update `StackTableViewController` property `currentTarget` in `commitEditingStyle`. Just update code in `StackTableViewController.m`:

Also if you use same code more than 2 times - better move it to separate function

```
- (id)init {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"StackTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Do something
        [self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];
        [self updateCurrentTarget];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    [self updateCurrentTarget];
}

- (void)updateCurrentTarget
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count == 0 && [self.fetchedResultsController.sections.firstObject count] == 0) {
        self.currentTarget = nil;
    } else {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
        Target *current = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.currentTarget = current.body;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    [[stack managedObjectContext] deleteObject:target];
    [stack saveContext];
    [self updateCurrentTarget];

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDeleteObject)]) {
        [_delegate didDeleteObject];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)goToStack:(id)sender {
    StackTableViewController *vc = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

This method should be as below:

```
- (IBAction)goToStack:(id)sender {
    StackTableViewController *vc = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init];
    vc.delegate = self.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

The reason for this is that you've setup HomeVC as delegate of StackTable in the init method, but you aren't using the same instance of StackTable and initializing a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need make 2 changes:

- In `goToStack:` add `vc.delegate = self` before `pushViewController:`
- In your `StackTableViewController tableView: commitEditingStyle:` update `currentTarget` before invoke `[_delegate didDeleteObject]`

Comment: my problem was that in the stack view controller I did not pop the view controller, So after I added in the viewWillDisappear     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 the problem solved...